# How do I get rid of the bar on the bottom of the screen that allows you to take pictures in xcode?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, camera

I want the user to be able to see the content from the back camera but I do not want them to be given the option of taking a picture of it. Is there a function that I can call to turn this feature off?

Comment: You mean you want raw camera data, not a photo picker interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into a similar situation. You will want to use `AVFoundation` to construct your own interface. Your question was not nearly specific enough, so I'll give you my assumption of your situation: you are trying to hide the `UIImagePicker` button so the user cannot take a picture. `UIImagePicker` does not offer much in the way of customization, so `AVFoundation` will be your best bet. Check out [this](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/taking-control-of-the-iphone-camera-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/) tutorial from Jameson Quave and it should help you understand what direction to be headed in. Cheers!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/index.html